# publisher an integer

Tags: ros, c++, tutorial, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
This is the code for publisher a string:

```
std_msgs::String msg;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hello world " << count;
msg.data = ss.str();
ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
```

If i want publisher an integer,  other to sobstitute string with for example int8
what i can do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53865/publisher-an-integer/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be something like this:

```
#include <std_msgs/Int8.h>

std_msgs::Int8 msg;
msg.data = 17;
ROS_INFO("%d", msg.data);
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-01-31**:
as per above but dont forget to set the variable with: std_msgs::Int8 msg; before you start to use it.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-31**:
Quite right. Answer updated.

**Comment by [MedoSalah97](https://answers.ros.org/users/57513/medosalah97/) on 2020-08-21**:
Thanks a lot